# Change specific imageView within one method

Tags: java, android, methods, imageview

So basically I have 5 imageViews and 5 files. I want to assign these files to each imageView without typing the code every time - It's inefficient.

I have this atm:

```
if(i==1){
    File imageFile = new File(path+files.get(i));
    checkOrientation(imageFile);
    if(files.get(i).endsWith("mp4")) {
        Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    } else {
        imageView2.setImageURI(null);
        imageView2.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path + files.get(i)));
        imageView2.setRotation(rotate);
    }
    imageView2.invalidate();
    Log.d("onCreate", "imageView2 set: " + path+files.get(i) + " rotation: " + rotate);
} if(i==2){
    File imageFile = new File(path+files.get(i));
    checkOrientation(imageFile);
    if(files.get(i).endsWith("mp4")){
        Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        imageView3.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    } else {
        imageView3.setImageURI(null);
        imageView3.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path + files.get(i)));
        imageView3.setRotation(rotate);
    }
    imageView3.invalidate();
    Log.d("onCreate", "imageView3 set: " + path+files.get(i) + " rotation: " + rotate);
}
```

Is there a way I can make a method that uses this code but the correct imageView is edited based on an input parameter? 
For example:

```
public void setImageView(int view, int i, File imageFile){
    if(files.get(i).endsWith("mp4")) {
        Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        imageView(view).setImageBitmap(bMap);
    } else {
        imageView(view).setImageURI(null);
        imageView(view).setImageURI(Uri.parse(path + files.get(i)));
        imageView(view).setRotation(rotate);
    }
    imageView(view).invalidate();
    Log.d("onCreate", "imageView set: " + path+files.get(i) + " rotation: " + rotate);
}
```

Is this possible in any way? I've tried to write the code as above but it doesn't like imageView(view).

I just want to avoid writing the same lines of code repeatedly.

Thanks,

Casey

Comment: why don't you pass the `ImageView` to the method as a parameter

Comment: Just did this! What an easy fix!! Shows how a fresh brain can help so much when you've been working on something for so long!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing @SpringBreaker 's reply I wrote this code:

```
setimageView(imageView1, i, imageFile);

private void setimageView(ImageView imageView, int i, File imageFile) {
    if(files.get(i).endsWith("mp4")){
        Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageURI(null);
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path + files.get(i)));
        imageView.setRotation(rotate);
    }
    imageView.invalidate();
    Log.d("onCreate", "imageView set: " + path+files.get(i) + " rotation: " + rotate);
}
```